# Allowing users to add HTML to BP Groups Description how can I error check html of users?

Tags: buddypress, html, description

I am trying to modify the Group Description field on Buddypress Groups so that they can take HTML but Buddypress has filters to prevent this.

I used this;

remove_filter( 'bp_get_group_description', 'bp_groups_filter_kses', 1 );
remove_filter( 'groups_group_description_before_save', 'wp_filter_kses', 1 );

These are the filters applied: https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/1.5.4/bp-groups/bp-groups-filters.php I experimented with removing them and was able to get the form to accept HTML.

BUT, the problem is if someone enteres broken html and leaves a closing tag out for example it breaks the page. I put it in protective Tags so the page wont break but the form itself can be broken with bad html being used in the form.

So my question is, is there a way to do error checking on the html and prevent open tags and bad code from being submitted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key filter is `force_balance_tags`. Don't remove that one, as it's responsible for making sure that HTML tags are closed.